# Blur image is overlap with the clear image if i reduce the image blur.. How can i restrict the overlap of the images?

Tags: css

Blur image is overlap with the clear image if i reduce the image blur.. How can i restrict the overlap of the images?

Please check my attachment here [image]

The problem is first image shows the background blur image !!

```css
.effet {
 width: 400px;
 height: 125px;
 margin: 0 auto 50px auto;
}
.profile-box{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    border: none !important;
    padding: 19.5px 10px;
    display: block;
}
.min_cir{
border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
.filtre--r {
    -webkit-mask: -webkit-radial-gradient( center, closest-side, transparent 30%, black 80%);
    -webkit-mask: radial-gradient( closest-side at center, transparent 50%, black 110%);
    -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
    mask: url('#mask-radial');
    filter: url('#filtre1');
 transform: scale(1.1);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-box">
 <div class="media">
  <a class="pull-left" href="">
   <!--<img class="img-circle" src="">-->
   <div class="effet">
   <img class="min_cir" src="http://i.imgur.com/oH1698V.jpg">
   <img class="filtre filtre--r min_cir" src="http://i.imgur.com/oH1698V.jpg">
   </div>
  </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

The two images are overlaped together.. Please help me..

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is first image shows the background blur image !!

No, what's happening is that the blurred image becomes partially transparent. It's this one that is shown on top of the original one.

To avoid it, you can either set a lower z-index on the blurred image, or declare its tag before the non-blurred image.

```css
effet {
  width: 400px;
  height: 125px;
  margin: 0 auto 50px auto;
}
.profile-box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  border: none !important;
  padding: 19.5px 10px;
  display: block;
}
.min_cir {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.filtre--r {
  -webkit-mask: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, closest-side, transparent 30%, black 80%);
  -webkit-mask: radial-gradient(closest-side at center, transparent 50%, black 110%);
  -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
  mask: url('#mask-radial');
  filter: blur(2px);
  transform: scale(1.1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-box">
  <div class="media">
    <a class="pull-left" href="">
      <div class="effet">
        <img class="filtre filtre--r min_cir" src="http://i.imgur.com/oH1698V.jpg" />
        <img class="min_cir" src="http://i.imgur.com/oH1698V.jpg">

      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
effet {
  width: 400px;
  height: 125px;
  margin: 0 auto 50px auto;
}
.profile-box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  border: none !important;
  padding: 19.5px 10px;
  display: block;
}
.min_cir {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.filtre--r {
  z-index: 0;
  -webkit-mask: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, closest-side, transparent 30%, black 80%);
  -webkit-mask: radial-gradient(closest-side at center, transparent 50%, black 110%);
  -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
  mask: url('#mask-radial');
  filter: blur(2px);
  transform: scale(1.1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-box">
  <div class="media">
    <a class="pull-left" href="">
      <div class="effet">
        <img class="min_cir" src="http://i.imgur.com/oH1698V.jpg">
        <img class="filtre filtre--r min_cir" src="http://i.imgur.com/oH1698V.jpg">
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```